# Alexa Skills Conversation

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am using Https Call for retrieve the data from the php code,
    I had one intent -> user will ask status of the user, @response i'm showing "Enter the User id".
    But getting the error "problem with Skills".
my code

```
else if($EchoReqObj->request->intent->name =="status"){
$text = "Please provide the id";
$array = array("version"=>"1.0","response"=>array("outputSpeech"=>array("type"=>"PlainText","text"=>$text),"directives"=>array("type"=>"Dialog.ElicitSlot","slotToElicit"=>"id"),"shouldEndSession"=>false));

echo json_encode($array);

}
```

Details:

```
Intent name: status
Intent Slot: id
```

Expected output:

```
user-> status of user.
alexa -> Enter user id.
user -> 123456
alexa -> status of user Active.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Share your response JSON

Comment: {
 "body": {
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
   "outputSpeech": {
    "type": "PlainText",
    "text": "Enter the user id"
   },
   "directives": [
    {
     "type": "Dialog.ElicitSlot",
     "slotToElicit": "id"
    }
   ],
   "shouldEndSession": false
  }
 }
}

Comment: i got the expected result thomas, did a small mistake in Https. thanks for Reply

Comment: Issue is in backEnd. can i have your social networking Id... :)

Comment: Please post it as an answer, others might find helpful.

Comment: Hello Thomas, Now i want to connect the skills to amazon echo dot. I connected amazon alexa app and connected device through app and enabled my skill,but while i am calling like ALEXA OPEN DEMO. It is returning the error message. kindly help me out of this error, where i am missing.

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving

Comment: It is working Fine in test console , Now i install amazon alexa app in my phone and connected device and enabled Skill, while i am calling skill it is saying " I not quite to sure that".

Comment: What is the language of yiur skill? English US? Then make sure that the language selected for echo is english US itself

Comment: Always raise new questions separately. It woukd ne helpful for others